# This platform does not support detach

Tags: python, celery

when i use `celery multi start w1 -A proj -l info` to start background workers, it throws a Runtime Error:

> This platform does not support detach

who can tell me how to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying it on Windows.

The exception is thrown from `celery.platforms.detached` function if `resourse` module was not imported. And that module is Unix-specific and cannot be imported on other platforms.

Celery's "[Running the worker as a daemon](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#windows)" page links to [this guide](http://www.calazan.com/windows-tip-run-applications-in-the-background-using-task-scheduler/) which explains how to "Run applications in the background using Task Scheduler".